# a.e convergence of càdlàg function

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having troubles with formally prove this:

Let $f:\mathbb{R_+} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a piecewise constant and càdlàg function
and define $$f^h(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f\left[(kh)^-\right]\mathbb{1}_{[kh,(k+1)h)}(x)$$
prove that $$f^{h}\stackrel{h\to 0}{\longrightarrow} f \quad \text{a.e}$$
Any help will be appreciated.